# SQL Query The Will Tell If Any Part On An Order Is Non-Stock

Tags: mysql

I don't really know the best way to word this question, so I had a hard time searching for a solution. I have a query that pulls all the orders on a given day. I need to know which orders have items on it where its inventory = 'N'. I'm not looking for it to find orders where ALL of the items are inventory ='N'. If there is at least one of them, I'd like it so say 'Y' in a separate column.

```
select 
a.OrderNum, 
c.Inventory,
case when c.inventory = 'n' then 'Y' else 'N' end as NonStock
from orders a inner join orditems b on a.ordnum = b.ordnum inner join items 
c on b.code = c.code
where a.OrderDate = '7/24/2017' 
group by a.OrderNum, c.Inventory
```

This is the original code that I came up with. I know this isn't correct. I need something similar (or completely different, I don't really know) where that NonStock column will say Y as long as any of the items from the order have c.inventory = 'N'. Am I going in the right direction at all? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Sample Data:

```
a.OrderNum  b.ItemNum  c.Inventory
123         3          Y
123         4          N
123         5          Y
124         6          Y
124         9          N
124         8          Y
125         11         Y
125         13         Y
125         15         Y
```

Desired Output:

```
a.OrderNum NonStock
123        Y
124        Y
125        N
```

Since orders 123 and 124 have an item on it that is c.inventory = 'N' they get triggered as Nonstock on the desired output. Order 125 has 3 items that are all c.inventory = 'Y' so it will get a 'N' for NonStock.

Answer (score 0):

That's look correct and you need to use a `CASE` expression for this purpose but don't see the need for using `group by` at all. I mean the line `group by a.OrderNum, c.Inventory`. Your query should just be

```
select OrderNum, max(NonStock) as NonStock
from (
select 
a.OrderNum, 
c.Inventory,
case when c.inventory = 'n' then 'Y' else 'N' end as NonStock
from orders a inner join orditems b on a.ordnum = b.ordnum inner join items 
c on b.code = c.code
where a.OrderDate = '7/24/2017' ) xxx
group by OrderNum;
```

Comment: If I don't use the group by, I get repeated order numbers. My end goal is to get a list of each order and whether or not it has any item on it where c.inventory = 'N'. Is there another way around that?

Comment: Actually, I was just thinking. What if I just do the opposite where if all items on the order are c.inventory = 'Y' then I know I don't have to worry about those and everything else will be what I'm looking for. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Vexxums, yes may be but can't say unless you post table structure, sample data and desired output

Comment: I edited my original post. I hope this gives you the information that you need. Thanks